# Some advice on program performance

Tags: c#

So I have a few developer questions to ask....

1. Is there ever a certain amount of lines of code after which the program will slow down?
   For example, my current major project has a total of over 6000 lines of code (including white-spaces). If this is bad, how can I spread my code out?
2. In Visual Studio 2012, how do I create a Class Library to hold a lot of my methods/utilities? I have seen that Visual Studio 2010 has the feature but 2012 doesn't. Also, will I benefit from a class library?
3. My current project layout is ONE .exe file with all the internal code etc compiled inside, I also have a number of icons as embedded resources. Does this affect performance?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. No. Program speed isn't related to number of lines of code. Program speed is related to how much it has to do, and how efficiently it is doing that (e.g. you could have efficient code that has to do an extremely huge amount, or inefficient code that has to do a large amount, and they can take the same amount of time to execute despite one program being 'better'), and of course how good the hardware it's being run on is and how much CPU time it's getting. The compiler will handle trivial optimizations for you, so you should focus on writing code that is as easy as possible to read.

Comment: (If your code IS running slow, 1) identify which part of it is running slow using a profiler. 2) Ask yourself if it needs to be made faster. 3) Perform optimization on which part of your program is taking up most of the time, starting with the biggest optimizations you can think of (like algorithmic changes to lower the time-complexity big O)

Comment: If you have performance problem - measure/use profiler and fix it. There is absolutely nothing can be said in general about "will XXX impact performance of *my* program".  Side note: Please don't ask multiple question in one.

Comment: This is 3 different questions. Please ask them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Lines of code are irrelevant. What matters is your code.
2. To [create a Class Library check out this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135.aspx). Sure you will benefit, you can build classes that can be used on other projects. The logic for web is on the `System.Web` DLL, you can choose to include it or not in a project. You can reuse code.
3. Embedded resources will not affect performance, but it will probably make your exe file bigger.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, size is fine for me!